# Resample Length Mismatch Error

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I get an error when I try to resample the following time series. It seems it fails only with 'MS' resampling. If I add one more row to the time series it goes through w/o any problems. Can figure out what's wrong here :(

```
dates=[datetime(2014,6,1),datetime(2014,10,1),datetime(2015,2,1)]
ts=pd.Series([1,1,0],index=dates)
ts

2014-06-01    1
2014-10-01    1
2015-02-01    0

ts.resample('MS')

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 9 elements
```

Comment: yes. the one below solved the issue. I marked it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you mention the argument `how`:

```
ts.resample('MS', how='mean')

#2014-06-01     1
#2014-07-01   NaN
#2014-08-01   NaN
#2014-09-01   NaN
#2014-10-01     1
#2014-11-01   NaN
#2014-12-01   NaN
#2015-01-01   NaN
#2015-02-01     0
```

Comment: Indeed, if how='mean' is explicitly passed to the method it works. Interesting... Thanks for helping out with that.